# DRF: only for representation purpose. How to combine two serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have

```
class Serializer1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ("first_name","last_name")

class Serializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ("phone","email")
```

Now I want to show both the serializers as one only for representation purpose

like

```
{
first_name:
last_name:
phone:
email:
}
```

How can do that

Comment: Have you tried using a `CombinedSerializer(serializers.Serializer)` and adding both model serializers as fields? Maybe overriding `to_representation()` would be necessary.

Comment: But i am afrad i will get nested dicts

Comment: I found a different approach [multiple models](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#). About your concern of nested dict. If you override `to_representation()` you can adjust the behaviour of displaying and avoid nested dicts.

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do this is unpack both `serializer.data` in a dict like:

```
s1 = Serializer1(obj)
s2 = Serializer2(obj)

combined = {**s1.data, **s2.data}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define the second serializer and then the first

```
class serializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = model2
        fields = '__all__'

class serializer1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    s2 = serializer2()
    class Meta:
        model = model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

then create a view using serializer1.

Comment: can we do something like,  writing this being half sure.                                                                     
        def list(self, request):                                                     
          mylist = []
            # q1 and q2 querysets
            for q in q1:
                mylist.append(o)
            for q in q2:
                mylist.append(o)
            queryset = mylist